# column does not belong to table

Tags: c#, sql, windows-mobile-6

```
try
        {
            objConn.Open();
            connexion.da = new SqlCeDataAdapter("Select NUM_PHY ,NOM_CLI ,NUM_FAC  ,DATE_FACT ,MODE_PAIEMENT   ,DATE_REG  from EXP WHERE NOM_CLI=@client  =@vari", objConn);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@client", client);

            da.Fill(ds,"EXP");


            DataRow drow = ds.Tables["EXP"].Rows[0];
            MessageBox.Show(drow["NOM_CLI"].ToString());

            MessageBox.Show(drow["NUM_PHY"].ToString());
```

I have this error :column 'NUM_PHY' does not belong to table EXP. 
Why this column and not others?

Comment: Seems silly but i'll ask, check table EXP, does the column NUM_PHY actually exist there?

Comment: check if this column is like that `num_phy` and not `NUM_PHY`

Comment: yes look commande it passed seccesfuly so the mater is not about name of colonne but something else

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code

```
DataRow drow = ds.Tables["EXPORT"].Rows[0];
```

with

```
DataRow drow = ds.Tables["EXP"].Rows[0];
```

Since you are filling the value in "EXP" Table.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check whether the column with the name "NUM_PHY" exists, and also I hope there has been no change in regional settings.

Comment: thanks for your anser .how can i know if there is change in regional settinng ?

Comment: If the code was working earlier and suddenly it has stopped, and also column exists in the table...so the only option left is regional settings might have got changed.

Comment: all columns work perfectly  except this column . and i have no error in select commande . you don't have any idea how can i change regional  setting